# How to fix codeblocks debugger's "unknown option 'nx'"

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

I am trying to debug my program using codeblock's debug option for the first time and I am getting an error message: "unknown option 'nx'". Because of which my debugger is not working and I am unable to use it, can anyone tell how to fix it?